# Show a zoomed SVG at designed size

Tags: javascript, svg, zooming

I have an SVG image which fits its parent `<object>` dimensions. The image is zoomed by changing its currentScale and currentTranslate properties. How can I scale the image to be shown at its intended size and center it in the viewport?

Example code:

```
<object width="500" height="300" data="pic.svg">
    <!-- The image will scale to be 300px heigh, 
         I need it to be shown at 32x32 and centered in the viewport,
         but could be zoomed to any size.
         Setting width and height attributes will crop the viewable area to 32x32,
         so we can't use this solution.
     -->
    <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" ... >
</object>
```

Comment: To be clear, it's the `<object>` tag's fallback content you're asking about? In that case you should note that the `<svg>` element sets up a viewport by itself so you need to specify that viewport (with the width and height attributes or via css width/height).

Comment: No, the `<svg>` here is for demonstration only, it's not fallback, but the DOM inside the `<object>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. To do this I got the intended size from width/height/viewbox (depending on which is available), made the viewBox equal the size of the available viewport (i.e. the containing `<object>` tag) and changed the x/y values of the viewBox attribute so that the image appears to be in the center of the viewport, and removed width and height attributes if they were present.

I use this in my [Opera SVG Viewer widget](http://widgets.opera.com/widget/15172/), you can see my SVG zooming library [here](http://code.google.com/p/opera-svg-viewer/source/browse/trunk/scripts/ZoomNPan.js).

Answer (score 0):

Set the `viewBox` attribute to encompass the area of the content (in local SVG coordinates) you want to display, but set the `height` and `width` attributes of the SVG to the number of pixels you want it to be displayed as on the web page.

Comment: It's written in the code above that width and height attributes crop the viewable area and can't be used in my case.

Comment: @SpadarShut Are you referring to the attributes on `<object>` or on the referenced `<svg>` element. What you are saying does not make sense to me; the interaction of the `viewBox` and the `width/height` is what controls the 'zoom' of your SVG image.

Comment: I'm saying about the attributes of the referenced svg. The image is zoomed dynamically by scrolling over it. Since the container `<object>` has the dimensions of 500x300 (in this example), the svg with a viewbox and no width/height attributes will initially be scaled to fit the container and setting `currentScale` to 1 after arbitrary zooming will return the `<svg>` to be 300px high. I need to find a way to zoom the image out (or in) to appear at the size of its viewBox values, 32x32 in this case.